# SharePoint communication site translate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, language-pack, google-translate

I need to transfer created communication site to different language.
Same as google translate works. Any idea how to translate like that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, take a look at [Machine Translation Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/machine-translation-services-in-sharepoint) in SharePoint that does exactly that.

> Machine Translation Service is a new service application in SharePoint
>   that provides automatic machine translation of files and sites. When
>   the Machine Translation Service application processes a translation
>   request, it forwards the request to the Microsoft Translator
>   cloud-hosted machine translation service, where the actual translation
>   work is performed. This cloud-service also powers the Microsoft
>   Office, Lync, Yammer and Bing translation features.